# ¿Cual es la función de un doble require en gulp?

Tags: nodejs, gulp, gulp-sass

Estoy iniciando en programación web y en un ejemplo con gulp para compilar sass encontré una sintaxis como la siguiente

```
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
```

Entiendo la primera parte de la asignación a la variable `const sass = require('gulp-sass')`, pero lo que no me queda claro es que y como funciona la segunda parte `(require('sass')`

En el ejemplo del video mencionan que es el compilador de sass que debe indicarse para que funcione, pero en rasgos generales mi pregunta seria **¿Que es esa sintaxis y como funciona?**

Espero puedan aclara mi duda

Answer (score 0):

Se podría decir que es una abreviación y puede expresarse también de esta otra manera para que sea más legible:

```
//Hacemos todas las llamadas. 
const gulp_sass = require('gulp-sass')
const compilador_sass = require('sass')
//Ejecutamos la función 
const sass = gulp_sass(compilador_sass)
```